# How to optimize str.replace() in Python

Tags: python, optimization, bit-manipulation

I am working on a binary string (i.e it only contains 1 and 0) and I need to run a function N number of times. This function replaces any instance of '01' in string to '10'. However, str.replace takes too much time to process the output, especially when the the length of string as well as N can be as big as 10^6.

I have tried implementing regex but it hasn't provided me with any optimization, instead taking more time to perform the task.

For example, if the string given to me is 01011 and N is equal to 1, then the output should be 10101. Similarly, if N becomes 2, the output becomes 11010 and so on.

Are there any optimizations of str.replace in python or is there any bit manipulation I could do to optimize my code?

Comment: str.replace can never be the answer, nor can regex given that to use either of those given your solution would be linear and would involve iteration over the string. however consider this, it is not guaranteed to happen N times given that eventually there might not be any 01 to swap which depends on the size of your string. in your example N can only be performed 3 times at most.

Comment: You want to perform an operation 10^6 times on an input that can be up to 10^6. That's 10^12 operations in total. That will take some time, no matter what.

Comment: You should think some more about a smarter approach. Basically, just do one pass over the string and find and replace the 01 with 10. Now you do not have to check the entire string again, but only those places where you changed something in the first iteration, and so on.

Comment: What should be the result for N=1 and 011? Should it be 101 or 110?

Comment: unless I am totally mistaken, all the 1s will end up in the beginning, and the 0s at the very end because you will always keep moving the 1s forward with your swapping

Comment: @aws_apprentice all the 1s will end up in beginning only for values of N beyond a certain threshold, not before that.

Comment: @tobias_k I understand it'll take some time, but a complexity of O(10^12) is something I want to reduce. With regards to your second comment, I have been trying that but it doesn't make much of a difference, especially when the occurrence of substring to be replaced is large. With regards to your third comment, it will be 101. 110 will be the case when N >= 2.

Comment: @Rosa I think it might be better to do this in C.

Comment: The main problem with `str.replace` is that strings are immutable. Each replacement creates a new string. Using some kind of array where each cell can be written to is a must.

Comment: @gmds I can do it in C but would it be any different from N traversals of whole string?

Comment: @VPfB yes that is true. But if we use an array/list, wouldn't it still amount to N traversals of the list?

Comment: @Rosa I think I have an algorithm with precomputed hashtables that schould allow for O(N) time complexity. But I will only be able to post it later.

Comment: @Rosa, Of course avoiding string does not improve the number of steps required, but individual 01->10 replacements would be much more efficient.

Comment: @MegaIng fair enough. Do post them though at the earliest.

Comment: @VPfB I'll give it a shot then and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's think of the input as bits forming an unsigned integer, possible a very large one. For example:

```
  1001 1011  # input number X
  0100 1101  # Y = X>>1 = X//2 -- to get the previous bit to the same column
  1001 0010  # Z1 = X & ~Y -- We are looking for 01, i.e. 1 after previous 0
  0001 0010  # Z2 = Z1 with the highest bit cleared, because we don't want
             # to process the implicit 0 before the number
  1010 1101  # output = X + Z2, this adds 1 where 01's are;
             # 1 + 01 = 10, this is what we want
```

Thus we can process the whole list just with few arithmetic operations.

---

Update: sample code, I tried to address the comment about leading zeroes.

```
xstr = input("Enter binary number: ")
x = int(xstr, base=2)
digits = len(xstr)
mask = 2**(digits-1) - 1 
print("{:0{width}b}".format(x,width=digits))

while True:
    z2 = x & ~(x >> 1) & mask
    if z2 == 0:
        print("final state")
        break
    x += z2
    print("{:0{width}b}".format(x,width=digits))
```

Comment: I'll surely get back to you once I try your approach. It looks promising, I wouldn't deny.

Comment: I am having trouble implementing this for strings with leading 0s in them since to use bit operators the string must be converted to binary which removes the leading 0s. Any idea how to tackle that in this approach since it works purely on bit operators?

Comment: @Rosa Can't you just ignore the leading zeros and add them Back later? Or add a 1 add the beginning and remove it at the end?

Comment: @MegaIng if the string is like 01... , the leading zero will make a difference. That's the issue. Even something like 000001... will give a different output if the leading zero is removed.

Comment: @Rosa My other approach should still work. I mistyped in the comment, I corrected it now.

Comment: @MegaIng The precomputed hashtables? I understand the concept but I am not sure how they can be used in this. Perhaps if you could provide some more details, I might be able to try it.

Comment: @Rosa I don't mean that, I mean what I wrote in the previous comment on this answer: You could add a `1` at the beginning of the string and srtip it away at the end. (Btw. I realized that the hashtable approaches breaks down for really big N. Mainly because of the Hashtable generation, e.g Storage Space complexity would be 4N Strings a length 2N. That's bad)

Comment: @Rosa I have udpated the answer with short code to play with.

Comment: @VPfB just one question. The last line, the print statement, that is purely for display formatting of the binary number without the leading 0b right? Or it serves another purpose I can't understand?

Comment: @Rosa The print statement just takes care of formatting (No 0b prefix, exact width, zero padded from left) and nothing else.

Comment: @Rosa I'm getting 00001 -> 00010 -> 00100 I think that's correct. If you found any error, please post the exact values

Comment: @VPfB that's why the leading zero issue since I wasn't printing the values. The formatting would have taken care of it. My bad

Comment: @Rosa I haven't tried large numbers, but Python3 has unlimited int size.

Comment: @VPfB but the thing about long strings still stands. Its taking more time than what I have been allotted. Do you feel a change of language, perhaps something faster like C, would help?

Comment: @VPfB I know that, but its taking too much time, atleast by the benchmarks I am supposed to comply with. Otherwise its working very well and solves the issue to a large extent.

Comment: @Rosa I think Python int is also not good enough for high performance. C would be much better, but if I recall correctly it has no command to bitwise shift large blocks of memory. Rotate through carry assembly instruction is useful for that. I would write the core of hte inner loop in assembly language.

Comment: @VPfB I understand. Tried it in C++ with same outcome. Will try to find a new approach now.

Answer (score 2):

While this is not an answer to the actual replacement question, my preliminary investigations show that the flipping rule will eventually arrange all the 1s at the beginning of the string and all the 0s at the end, so the following function will give the correct answer if N is close to `len(s)`.

```
from collections import Counter

def asymptote(s, N):
    counts = Counter(s)
    return '1'*counts['1'] + '0'*counts['0']
```

I compared the results with

```
def brute(s, N):
    for i in range(N):
        s = s.replace('01', '10')
    return s
```

This graph shows where we have agreement between the brute force method and the asymptotic result for random strings

[image: Asymptotic result compared]

The yellow part is where the brute force and asymptotic result are the same. So you can see you need at least `len(s)/2` flips to get to the asymptotic result most of the time and sometimes you need a bit more (the red line is 3*len(s)/4).

Comment: The asymptote method wouldn't work when N is less below a certain value such that all 0s do not go to end.

Comment: @Rosa Correct, this only works as I mention in my answer for "large" N. From my experiments this is somewhere around `3*len(s)/4`

Comment: I see. Fair enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the program I spoke of:

```
from typing import Dict

from itertools import product

table_1 = {
    "01": 1,
    "11": 0,
}

tables = {
    1: table_1
}


def _apply_table(s: str, n: int, table: Dict[str, int]) -> str:
    tl = n * 2
    out = ["0"] * len(s)
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == '1':
            if i < tl:
                t = '1' * (tl - i - 1) + s[:i + 1]
            else:
                t = s[i - tl + 1:i + 1]
            o = table[t]
            out[i - o] = '1'
    return ''.join(out)


def _get_table(n: int) -> Dict[str, int]:
    if n not in tables:
        tables[n] = _generate_table(n)
    return tables[n]


def _generate_table(n: int) -> Dict[str, int]:
    def apply(t: str):
        return _apply_table(_apply_table(t, n - 1, _get_table(n - 1)), 1, table_1)

    tl = n * 2
    ts = (''.join(ps) + '1' for ps in product('01', repeat=tl - 1))
    return {t: len(apply(t).rpartition('1')[2]) for t in ts}


def transform(s: str, n: int):
    return _apply_table(s, n, _get_table(n))
```

This is not very fast, but `transform` has a time-complexity of `O(M)` with M being the length of the string. But the space-complexity and the bad time complexity of the `_generate_table` function makes it unusable :-/ (It may however be possible that you can improve it, or implement it in C for faster speed. (It also gets better if you store the hash-tables and not recompute them every time)

Comment: I appreciate your effort but I am unable to understand the code, like the role of functions. Could you please explain them?